# How to indicate if a number is odd or even in PHP in an HTML file

Tags: php, html

Im new to PHP and mysql, we have been set exercises in different rectangles in an HTML file. 
2 rectangles in this exercise are

Rectangle 5: An "input field" that allows you to input a four digit integer number or a four letter string and store it in a variable "$x". A user will put the numbers/letters in a box and click on a button labelled "submit" in order to enter the number/letter into the variable.

Rectangle 6: An output that indicates if a number "$x" input by the user is even or odd.

I have got rectangle 5 to work and display variable $x a the top of the screen, however I cant seem to get rectangle 6 to work.

Here is my code so far:

```
function rect5if() { //rect5 if statement
    if( $_POST['name'] && $_POST['name'] != ""){
        $x = urldecode( $_POST['name'] );                
    } else {
        $x = "not set";
    }
    echo $x;
}//end of rect5

function rect6oddeven() {
    if(is_int($x/2)) {
        echo("Even");
    } else {
        echo("Odd");
    }
}

echo " <table border='1'>
<td>Rectangle 5 ".rect5if()."
<form method=\"post\" >
Enter four digit number/letter string
<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" maxlength=\"4\">
<input type=\"submit\" />
</form></td> 
<td>Rectangle 6 ".rect6oddeven()."</td>
</tr>
</table> ";
```

Any suggestions? Thanks GL

Comment: What is `$x` supposed to be in the `rect6oddeven()` scope ?

Comment: I suggest looking into the modulus operator (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: The number is odd if `number % 2 != 0`, even otherwise

Comment: And use `is_numeric()` instead of `is_int()` to check whether it is numeric. `is_int` will return false for a string of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

maybe not obvious use of the modulus (%) operator is to check if an integer is odd or even.

```
<?php
if (($a % 2) == 1)
{ echo "$a is odd." ;}
if (($a % 2) == 0)
{ echo "$a is even." ;}
?>
```

Comment: if () else () must be better :).

Answer (score 2):

You need to check what remainder of division by 2 will give you. If it will be 0, number is even, otherwise it's odd. Operator that does that is named modulus. I suggest you googling it to learn it.

Working code, assuming `$x` is is given value earlier in the code:

```
function rect6oddeven() {
  if ($x % 2 === 0) {
    echo("Even");
  }
  else {
    echo("Odd");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why it needs to be text. It does work either way.
But you should use the html *number* attribute:

```
<input type=\"number\" name=\"name\" maxlength=\"4\" >
```

you could also use "min" and set that to 4. So the user would have to enter a 4 digit value.

Here is the function:

```
function rect6oddeven(){
    $x = urldecode( $_POST['name'] );
    if(is_numeric($x)){
        if($x % 2 == 0) {
            return "It's even";
        }else{
            return "It's odd";
        }
    }
}
```

Or even better, declare $x before you initiate any functions.
Then you're doing both exercises in one.

```
<?
echo " <table border='1'>

<td>Rectangle 5 
<form method=\"post\" >
Enter four digit number/letter string
<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" maxlength=\"4\">
<input type=\"submit\" />
</form></td> 


<td>Rectangle 6 ".rect6oddeven()."</td>
</tr>
</table> ";

$x = urldecode( $_POST['name'] );
function rect6oddeven(){
    if(is_numeric($x)){
        if($x % 2 == 0) {
            return "It's even";
        }else{
            return "It's odd";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You should really work this out yourself, asking other people to work it out for you simply removes the joy of programming.

Answer (score 0):

@frz3993 had it right.  Your problem is scope.  (Yes, using the `%` operator is better here, but it's not the main problem).

You define `$x` in one function.  That variable is local to that function.  In another function you can have `$x` but it's not the same `$x`.  You *could* declare it global, but better to use a class since global variables are to be avoided whenever possible.  For example:

```
<?php

class Page{
    private $x;

    function __construct(){
        if( $_POST['name'] && $_POST['name'] != ""){
          $this->x = urldecode( $_POST['name'] );                
        }else{
          $this->x = false; 
        }
    }

    function rect5if(){
        if( false === $this->x ) {
            return "not set";
        } else {
            return $this->x;
        }
    }

    function rect6oddeven(){
        if( false === $this->x ) {
            return '';
        } else {
            if( $this->x % 2 === 0 ) {
                return "even";
            } else {
                return "odd";
            }
        }
    }
}

$page = new Page();

?>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>Rectangle 5 <?= $page->rect5if(); ?>
            <form method="post" >
                Enter four digit number/letter string
                <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="4">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </td> 
        <td>Rectangle 6 <?= $page->rect6oddeven(); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The constructor reads in the data and stores it in the class variable `x`.  Each of the functions can then access the same data since they are part of the same class.