# PHP input and output of four digit integer

Tags: php, html

Attempting to create an input field of a 4 digit number or four letter string and store it in variable `$x` in PHP. 
Also attempting to create an output that indicates whether `$x` is odd or even.

Have been able to create the input field and store the string, however I can't seem to get the output to display whether its odd or even for some reason, here is my code so far:

```
<td>
    <form method="post">
        Enter four digit number/letter string <input type="text" name="name"
            maxlength="4"> <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</td>
<?php
if ($_POST ['name'] && $_POST ['name'] != "") {
    $x = urldecode ( $_POST ['name'] );
} else {
    $x = "not set";
}

echo "$x" . "<br/>";
?>
</td>

<td>
<?php
$x = urldecode ( $_POST ['name'] );
if (is_numeric ( $x )) {
    if ($x % 2 == 0) {
        return "It's even";
    } else {
        return "It's odd";
    }
}
echo "$x";
?>
</td>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks 
G

Comment: don't use urldecode and is_numeric

Comment: in addition to what Lashane said, return does not do any output... try print or echo instead http://de1.php.net/manual/de/function.return.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` is used to return data from a function.  You don't have a function.  You seem to already know about `echo`, and you did it correctly here [How to indicate if a number is odd or even in PHP in an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463997/how-to-indicate-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even-in-php-in-an-html-file):

```
echo "It's even";
```

And:

```
echo "It's odd";
```